# Angular2 + ng-bootstrap on server side templates

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, ng-bootstrap

I have Angular2 (2.0.0) with ng-bootstrap on my server side application. All the templates are rendered using php (not angular).

When I any include any ng-bootstrap snippet from server side, it does not work. But if I include them from angular template inside `<app-root>...</app-root>` then it works.

I basically need to include dropdown, modal, alert... anywhere on the template as direct directive style. How is that possible?

```
<body>

<h1>Title 1</h1>

<p>This is para...</p>

<app-root></app-root> <!-- any ng-bootstrap directives are accessable inside app-root -->

<!-- I'm not rendered as ng-bootstrap directive, since its not inside app-root -->
<ngb-alert [dismissible]="false">
    <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</ngb-alert>


 <!--script tags are included here for angular2-->

</body>
```

Comment: You'll need to provide some concrete code samples.

Comment: added code sample

Comment: Well, put it under app-root, otherwise app-root is not you app root anymore.

Comment: How can I put it outside app-root, since 90% application and template is generated from the server.

Comment: I don't understand how the fact that the template is generated by the server prevents it from generating a template where the alert is inside the app-root rather than outside. You'll need to explain that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an Angular2 component as direct child of `<body>`, you have to bootstrap it. This means you need an `NgModule` with that component in `bootstrap: [NgbAlert]` and then call `platform.bootstrapModule(NgbAlertModule)`.
This creates a new Angular2 application on your page for each bootstrapped module.

Comment: Where should I import `platform.bootstrapModule` from?

Comment: What does "inculded inside bootstrap" mean? Can you please edit your question and add the updated code there?

Comment: As the error message says, `Alert` is not a component. You can't bootstrap directives.

Comment: What is `NgbAlert`?

Comment: Sorry, out of ideas.

Comment: Is it possible to bootstrap body tag without replacing pre-template inside? because that might also work, if we just bootstrap complete body

Comment: No, if you use `body` as selector the content of `<body>` will be purged. There was already a question today how to bootstrap two components with an answer. Perhaps that helps solve your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717949/get-bootstraped-component/39721123#39721123