# Get bootstraped component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple `@NgModule` the boostrap 2 components :

```
// Global module for all Angular Component
@NgModule({
    declarations: Components, // directives, components, and pipes owned by this NgModule
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule],
    providers: Providers,
    bootstrap: [Menu, Main]
})
export class MenuModule { }
```

I want to store a reference of my `Main` component bootstraped by my `MenuModule`. I tried to implement the `.then` method of `bootstrapModuleDynamic()`, but I only get the factory of the component.

```
// Bootstrap of module
platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(MenuModule)
    .then((menuModule: NgModuleRef<MenuModule>) => {
        var test: ComponentFactory<Main> = (<any>menuModule).bootstrapFactories[0];
    });
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see two ways to get list of bootstraped components:

1) Using `ApplicationRef`

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
    .bootstrapModule(MenuModule)
    .then((menuModule: NgModuleRef<MenuModule>) => {
        const appRef = menuModule.injector.get(ApplicationRef);
        const components = appRef.components;      
    });
```

2) Using `ngDoBootstrap` method on your module:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [Components, // directives, components, and pipes owned by this NgModule
    imports: [BrowserModule, HttpModule, FormsModule],
    providers: Providers,
    entryComponents: [Menu, Main]
    // bootstrap: [Menu, Main]
})
export class MenuModule {
   ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
     const compRefMenu = appRef.bootstrap(Menu);
     const compRefMain = appRef.bootstrap(Main);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! I choose the first solution.

Comment: How do you load that NgModuleRef and ApplicationRef in the main.ts @ChristopheGigax

Comment: @ChristopheGigax, can you share me the code please for loading the above procedure.

Comment: I don't have the code anymore, sorry. It was a long time ago. Maybe you can find the `NgModuleRef` with the `then` method of the `bootstrapModule` method.

Comment: @ChristopheGigax, thanks for your reply. Can you help any manner how you have written that, where in which file like main.ts, or module file. As I have tried it, but both the solution is not working. If possible try to remember and help me.

Comment: Why don't you store you component instance when it's bootstrap from himself ? Like into the `constructor` of `ngOnInit` ?

Comment: Hello yurzui, why root services shared across `appRef.bootstrap(Menu);` and `appRef.bootstrap(Main);` as singltone service. Why appRef does not create own instance of service for each app?