# Is it possible to run one Angular 2 app several times in one page?

Tags: asp.net, angular, webforms, angular-bootstrap

I'm making migration from asp.net web forms to Angular 4. I'm making it step by step. Replacing one part and placing it in production. I face a problem with loading same Angular app several times in page. For example with code

```
<root tag="table-ep-component" data="5800"></root>
<root tag="table-ep-component" data="3333"></root>
```

there is only one loaded app in the page - the first one. How can I make them work both? Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Why do you need the same app multiple times, rather than the same component multiple times within one app?

Comment: Main page markup is generated by asp.net web forms so far and we are not close to full migration to Angular4. Asp.net web forms tells that this component should be in this place. Some components are Angular4 apps. And sometimes it should be several Angular4 components in one pages in different places. Haven't found other real life approach to migrate from web forms to Angular step by step and can not migrate in one step - too much work for one step.

Comment: You can render app one time on first demand and put needed component inside. When this part is not needed you hide tag and work with another parts of system. Next time you need angular form you show root container and put another form into it. What do you think? Just thoughts, I don't know how to do this :)

Comment: Sometime I will need to show several Angular components in different places. Could imaging this working with some DOM manipulations. Like Load this component inside root and than move it to other place. Doesn't look like any reliable thing. still, thanks for idea (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Applicationref.bootstrap` method to do it working:

```
abstract bootstrap<C>(
  componentFactory: ComponentFactory<C>|Type<C>,
  rootSelectorOrNode?: string|any): ComponentRef<C>;
```

As we can see this method can take `rootSelectorOrNode` parameter so we can bootstrap the same component twice.

`ngDoBootstrap` method on your root `@NgModule` can help us to manually bootstrap our application:

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [AppComponent],
   imports: [BrowserModule], 
   entryComponents: [AppComponent]
})
export class MenuModule {
   ngDoBootstrap(appRef: ApplicationRef) {
     const rootElements = document.queryselectorAll('root');
     // cast due to https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4947
     for (const element of rootElements as any as HTMLElement[]){
       appRef.bootstrap(AppComponent, element);
     }
   }
}
```

See also:

- [Angular 2 stand alone components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41118925/angular-2-stand-alone-components)
- [Changing shared data between root modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39686305/changing-shared-data-between-root-modules)
- [Get bootstraped component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39717949/get-bootstraped-component/39721123#39721123)

Comment: it looks like what I need. Except for ngDoBootstrap don't called. Placed console.log where. 
I compile with Angular CLI in production mode with AoT. Investigating why doesn't it called.

Comment: You should remove bootstrap property from NgModule metadata

Comment: Why this approach shares all root services aross all apps? The same instance of services. How to set Angular to use separate services despite they are a root?