# Repeating root tag in index.html

Tags: angular

Why does repeating `<app-root>` tag in my index.html have no effect? For example, if my app.component.html has a simple `Hello World` and if I write

```
<app-root></app-root>
<app-root></app-root>
<app-root></app-root>
```

in index.html, the browser displays only one `Hello World` and not

```
Hello World
Hello World
Hello World
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because angular selects root element through:

```
document.querySelector(selectorOrNode)
```

where `selectorOrNode` is the root component selector.

As you can guess it will always return only first element.

If you want to apply root component to several elements then you can use `ngDoBootstrap` as described here:

- [Is it possible to run one Angular 2 app several times in one page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896367/is-it-possible-to-run-one-angular-2-app-several-times-in-one-page)